# How to toggle audio in React functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, html5-audio

I am trying to play/stop an audio when clicking an `<img />`. Each `<img />` is related to a different audio file. The audio should loop while the user do not stop it. I prefer to not use classes components because I could use hooks.

My actual code do not stop the audio; do not loop it; and if I click twice the audio is overlaped (two sounds at the same time).

```
import myJSON from "./assets/myJSON.json";

export default function Card() {
 
    const handleClick = (argument) => {
        new Audio(argument.target.dataset.sound).play()
    }
    
    return (
        <>
            {myJSON.map((myObject, index) => {
                return (
                    <img
                        src={myObject.image}
                        alt={myObject.name}
                        key={index}
                        onClick={handleClick} 
                        data-sound={myObject.sound}
                    />
                );
            })}
        </>
    );
}
```

I am free to change the json or try a different approach.

Comment: All that your click event does is play the URL... You need to add state that will allow the component to know if it is currently playing. And modify the state as needed...

Comment: Agreed, and I would suggest also using a ref to store the currently playing  audio element so you can toggle the play/pause state of that stream. Would allow you to also stop any playing streams if user clicks to play another sound (*unless you want them to play concurrently*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a code sandbox for you that you can access here: https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-hypatia-8fwun?file=/src/App.js

I have created a sample of how I would approach something along these lines:

**Please Note:** the order of the array matters as I am going off of the index to decide what song plays and what doesn't. You don't necessarily have to take this approach. This is just a quick and dirty solution.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [musicArray] = useState([
    "https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Kalimba-online-audio-converter.com_-1.wav",
    "https://www2.cs.uic.edu/~i101/SoundFiles/BabyElephantWalk60.wav"
  ]);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const musicData = musicArray.map((sound) => {
      return { audio: new Audio(sound), play: false };
    });

    setData(musicData);
  }, [musicArray]);

  const playSound = (index) => {
    setData((arr) =>
      arr.map((sound, i) => {
        if (i === index) {
          sound.audio.play();
          return { ...sound, play: true };
        }
        sound.audio.pause();
        return { ...sound, play: false };
      })
    );
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(data);
  }, [data]);

  const stopSound = (index) => {
    setData((arr) =>
      arr.map((sound, i) => {
        if (i === index) {
          sound.audio.pause();
          return { ...sound, play: false };
        }
        return { ...sound, play: false };
      })
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {data.map((sound, i) => {
        return (
          <>
            {sound.play ? (
              <button onClick={() => stopSound(i)}>pause</button>
            ) : (
              <button onClick={() => playSound(i)}>play</button>
            )}
          </>
        );
      })}

      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. But inside the `stopSound` after the `if ( )  { }` we have `return { ...sound, play: false };`, I am not sure, but I think just `return { ...sound };` would work too.

Comment: but no problem!